# MVC 4 Web Api Security from C.S.R.F. Attacks

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I am using asp.net mvc4 web api. I am using Form Authentication for security. I have asp form pages(.aspx) at client side. Is there any way to implement Antiforgery in this scenario. please describe i  detail. I have done it in cshtml pages but found no any way to implement it in .aspx forms.

Comment: Your question is valid and I see no answers since Oct 10, 2013. By now I am sure you have seen this video http://vimeo.com/43603474

Answer (score 0):

You might have found the solution for this, still adding reference to the page where you can find how to use CSRF prevention in ASP.Net

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/